# How to get QTreeWidgetItem if its ItemWidget is known

Tags: python, pyqt

After creating LineEdit widget:

```
lineEdit=QtGui.QLineEdit()
```

and assigning it to `QTreeWidgetItem` as an itemWidget:

```
tree=QtGui.QTreeWidget()
item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(tree)
tree.setItemWidget(item, 0, lineEdit)
```

Knowing `lineEdit` variable how can I query what QTreeWidgetItem it is assigned to as an itemWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LAST EDITED : 12 / 8 / 2014 9 : 12**

My solution, create own method to find `QTreeWidgetItem` by part argument `QWidget`, Like this (use recursive function);

```
class customQTreeWidget (QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    .
    .
    .
    def findItemWidget (self, findQWidget, currentQTreeWidgetItem = None):
        if currentQTreeWidgetItem == None:
            currentQTreeWidgetItem = self.invisibleRootItem()
        for index in range(self.topLevelItemCount()):
            if findQWidget is self.itemWidget(currentQTreeWidgetItem, index):
                return currentQTreeWidgetItem
        for index in range(currentQTreeWidgetItem.childCount()):
            foundQWidget = self.findItemWidget(findQWidget, currentQTreeWidgetItem.child(index))
            if foundQWidget != None:
                return foundQWidget
```

Then, your want you call you can use this;

```
foundQTreeWidgetItem  = self.findItemWidget(findQWidget) # Don't part argument currentQTreeWidgetItem use in recursive loop
```

---

**itemWidget method Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreewidget.html#itemWidget

---

Regards,

Comment: I hoped there is a built-in one! Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. But, I can't found there is built-in method. we need make your own.